# Android game types database design

Tags: android, database

Im trying to make a game where a user can create his own game. What I mean with that is every game has subgames with different types in any order the user want.

Lets say I have 3 game types like:

1. jumpGame
2. watchGame
3. drawGame

So the user can create a game like:

**Game1**

1. jumpGame
2. jumpGame
3. jumpGame
4. drawGame

**Game2**

1. watchGame
2. drawGame
3. watchGame
4. drawGame
5. drawGame

I need to save the game in a database so the user can continue it later. My idea was to design the databse like:

**Game**
id

**subGames**
id, type, order, gameId, idOfTypeTable

And then create for **every type of game a different table** with needed records. This creates alot of tables. Is there a better way for this database design?

Comment: Use a ["link" (aka "junction")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)  table to implement `many-to-many` relationship between Users and Games.

Comment: @PM77-1 The problem is more that i have different game types and i dont know how to add them properly to a game. the gametypes have different propertys/screens so i need to seperate them somewhere in my database